# People are interested in my question. Why should others be able to close it

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

People are interested in my question. Why should the condecension of others result in the interested people being denied open discourse on the topic of interest?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393273/looking-for-security-exploit-to-android-licensing-closed

Comment: Because nobody understood what the question was. [Expository](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expository_writing) posts are not encouraged on SO.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for how I can get people interested in this topic without being so expository?

Comment: Who is interested in the question? It has 2 upvotes, not even enough to re-open

Comment: I don't know who down voted your answer here but I think it is very good that you came here to ask why was you question closed! It is what you should do, as for the original question, Brad Larson did an excellent job answering why your question got closed. Don't give up on you question, you'll sure find great answers here but please be more specific, thats' "the trick"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, you appeared to be asking for a code review.  Generally, dumping a bunch of code in your question and asking "Can you find a problem with this?" is frowned upon here.  You're asking people to do a lot of work for you in those cases, and the resulting answers often are not useful to anyone beyond yourself.

It's better if you can meet us halfway by focusing attention on a specific area with a directed question.  Perhaps you could call out one or two areas that you believe to be vulnerable to attack and describe what they do, rather than ask for any vulnerabilities in your entire implementation.

Comment: excellently put. Really!

Comment: I did just that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414449/does-anyone-see-vulnerabilities-in-my-caching-of-obfuscated-key-technique

Comment: @hunterp - Now that's a good question, and I see you're already getting quality responses.  Nice job on the rewording.